# Конфликт библиотек, что делать?

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

Есть две библиотеки

```
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
```

Они нормально между собой не работаю. Суть в том, что нормально не работает черная тема при обновлении страницы. Она то отображается  корректно то нет вместо черной темы грузиться белая.

Если убрать рекламу и соответственно и библиотеку рекламы то все норм.
Пробовал обновить библиотеку рекламы  на последнюю версию все также и откатить вплоть до самой первой ничего не дает .

А если обновить библиотеку appcompat то тема работает нормально но появляются другие проблемы . пробивал откатить  бесполезно.

Подскажите любые мысли будут полезны .
P.s
-хотелось бы остаться на firebase
- и желательно не сильно изменять программу !!

Comment: Из той библиотеки, где более старая версия, можно исключить проблемную библиотеку. Или исключить из обоих и скачать подходящую версию обоим.

Comment: По подробней пожалуйста , очень интересно. То есть   в библиотеке  есть конкретные модули . И какой то модуль вызывает неправильную работу 
. Нужно  как то  найти его и удалить .